# How to get the latest data of a specific day? [MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max, distinct

How can I get the latest data of a specific day in MySQL?

Let's assume that I have a column of dates recorded on my database

```
dates      |     time     |    value
---------------------------------------------
2015-08-05 |    11:03:02  |    200       
2015-08-05 |    23:04:22  |    2400
2015-08-07 |    8:00:22   |    500
2015-08-08 |    13:00:11  |    400
2015-08-08 |    13:23:11  |    200
2015-08-09 |    17:00:23  |    2200
2015-08-09 |    17:06:00  |    1290
2015-08-09 |    19:22:00  |    900
2015-08-13 |    01:01:22  |    1010
```

I want to get the latest data or transaction of a specific date, my desired result would be like this

```
 dates      |     time    |     value
---------------------------------------------       
2015-08-05  |   23:04:22  |    2400
2015-08-07  |   8:00:22   |    500
2015-08-08  |   13:23:11  |    200
2015-08-09  |   19:22:00  |    900
2015-08-13  |   01:01:22  |    1010
```

Only the latest data of a spefic or distinct date is chosen, what is the possible query with this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this way to get that for each dates

```
select t1.dates,t1.time,t1.value from table as t1 inner join
(
select dates,max(time) as time from table group by dates
) as t2 on t1.dates=t2.dates and t1.time=t2.time
```

Comment: this makes sense, as opposed to the other answers :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just curious what INNER JOIN for? I only have one table.

Comment: The inner join is required on the same table. The table aliased as t2 finds the maximum time for each date and it is joined with the same table using date and maximum time to get the value available

Comment: I tried applying your code above on my project but still it returns the same original table.

Comment: what is the datatype of time?

Comment: @Madhivanan, here is my sql.

`SELECT t1.time_modified,t1.date_modified,t1.balance_after_approval FROM tbl_savingrequest AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT date_modified,MAX(time_modified) AS time FROM tbl_savingrequest GROUP by date_modified) AS t2 ON t1.date_modified = t2.date_modified AND t1.time_modified AND t2.time
WHERE t1.user_id = '64401022' AND t1.request_status = '1';

Comment: @NielSinel There is an error at AND `t1.time_modified AND t2.time`. Should be `=`.

Comment: It only returns one row that contains the latest date, the other does not.

Comment: @NielSinel You should use the WHERE conditions in the select for the derived table. Otherwise the derived table could contain a value for the latest time which does not match your conditions. Then there will be no result for the entire date.

Comment: Your original post did not say anything about other conditions. Can you try this  SELECT t1.time_modified,t1.date_modified,t1.balance_after_approval FROM tbl_savingrequest AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT date_modified,MAX(time_modified) AS time_modified FROM tbl_savingrequest 
WHERE user_id = '64401022' AND request_status = '1'
GROUP by date_modified) AS t2 ON t1.date_modified = t2.date_modified AND t1.time_modified =t2.time_modified
WHERE t1.user_id = '64401022' AND t1.request_status = '1';

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY dates ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY dates HAVING time <= '23:59:59' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This will return one row; the OP is asking for one row per day. And you can't use the `having` clause like that: it requires an aggregate for `time`. Even if you could, a filter on `time <= 23.59:59` will accomplish nothing, because `23:59:59` is the highest time there is.

Comment: Ye, the sql is good and understandable than others but it only returns 1 row?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `dates`, MAX(`time`) AS `time`, MAX(`value`) AS `value`
FROM `tbl_name`
GROUP BY `dates`
ORDER BY `dates` ASC
```

Comment: `max(value)` displays the highest, not the latest, value

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY dates ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: But how could you get the data with specific day using this query  ?

Comment: The `group by` will make this return a random row for each `date`.  Then the `order by .... limit` will pick the latest 5 out of these random rows.